# Transform array of objects to single object and map types in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, generics

Few days ago, I created a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69299590/transform-array-of-objects-to-single-object-and-keep-types-in-typescript?noredirect=1) about transforming of array of objects to single object and keep types. However, I provided simplified situation, which did not solve my problem.

I have two classes `Int` and `Bool` which are children of `Arg` class. There are also 2 factory functions `createInt` and `createBool`.

```
class Arg<Name extends string> {

    protected name: Name

    public constructor(name: Name) {
        this.name = name
    }

}

class Int<Name extends string> extends Arg<Name> {}
class Bool<Name extends string> extends Arg<Name> {}

const createInt = <Name extends string>(name: Name) => new Int<Name>(name)
const createBool = <Name extends string>(name: Name) => new Bool<Name>(name)
```

Now, I would like to define arguments (`Int` or `Bool` with specified name) in array and function, that accept maped types of arguments (`Number` for `Int`, `Boolean` for `Bool`) in argument.

```
const options = {
    args: [
        createInt('age'),
        createBool('isStudent')
    ],
    execute: args => {
        args.age.length // Should be error, property 'length' does not exist on type 'number'.
        args.name // Should be error, property 'name' does not exist in 'args'.
        args.isStudent // Ok, boolean.
    }
}
```

I found [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56949513/typescript-type-of-a-property-dependent-on-another-property-within-the-same-obj) about mapping types, but I don't know how to map this `args` array to `args` object, so for now, I have just string there and loosing info about argument types.

```
type Options = {
    args: Arg<string>[],
    execute: (args: Record<string, any>) => void
}
```

Is there any way to do this and keep argument types in execute function? Here is a [demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECCBOBzAPAOTAWwKbSwDwBcsA7AExggPgEtjEA%20aAbwCgXoPoAHeAeyOBFS0YpiwAuaOmxtO3AK4AjENWDRgvYpXjzBveAApR2SdKwBKZuzmcCAC2oQAdMZwBeEWOscAvmz8soJAwAJLEBGhiuIQk5NDatAzRRGQwCChmjEx%20QVDQAEK8vCCR2MmxFFSJjPgpcemlWFkBGloE6vBYYERh7R6N5anxVXT0RmKmYpZujMRYAO7QvY1jruaBmpQdXUSFxdD9ZoNxCaPjJlJTB7MLBUUlmecWbAQAnlw4APJcBNSbB1Y5GAkBBJA1TgwANoAXQANN5olhgPIiJIDMDEKDoAAlJH6UjICGw6BgYivejTRgAN141FILACGza0F4Pz%20Wkk31%20-w8rCBIMkkIRcmAnW6WF6BgA5GBEFgpeZ4TZOKKdlg9iBpY4AMoEeSkEgEBUIuEI-BIlESEkg66A5XWzFOWVYJwgEiIezQAD0Xug2rsvHkIGEihwWHgfHgxJ4rPDb2gUrddHsUugpF4WBgxH40Uc7U00DeHwTxHkGFD8ClTmFnAxzlc3t9-sDwegodwEf00b4H3g8alrlT6czIhz%20Dz0FoCbrVZrHDrTh1eoN4Ub0E%20AGtiYp7l1iNW5H4fEA).

Comment: Does [this code](https://tsplay.dev/W4p0OW) meet your needs?  Your example has several problems; the first is that `Arg<N>` knows nothing of the type of value it represents; we need to fix that, so `Arg<N, V>`.  Then there is no specific type corresponding exactly to your `Options` type, so we need to make that generic also, `Options<A>` where `A` corresponds to an array of `Arg<?, ?>` types.  You can get type inference the way you want, but it involves making more things generic and adding a helper function.  Let me know if I should write that up or if I'm missing something.

Comment: @jcalz Thank you for help, that's exactly what I needed. Please, write answer to this question, so I can mark it as solved.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems with your example code that are hindering you from finding a solution.   We will fix each one in turn until we have working code.

---

First, your definition of `Arg<N>` only strongly types the `name`, corresponding to a property *key*.  If you want the compiler (and indeed, your code) to know anything about the type of the *value* of the property, then you will need to extend the definition of `Arg` to include it.  For example:

```
class Arg<N extends string, V> {
  public constructor(protected name: N, protected value: V) { }
}
```

Here we have added a second [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameter `V` to correspond to the type of the value.  Also, since TypeScript's type system is [structural](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html#structural-type-system) and not [nominal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominal_type_system), it means that you can't just add a type parameter *named* `V` and expect it to constrain anything.  If you want the compiler to consider `Arg<N, V>` to depend on `N` and `V`, it must depend *structurally* or [weird things might happen](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-doesnt-type-inference-work-on-this-interface-interface-foot--).  The easiest way to do this is to give `Arg` a property of type `V`. Maybe in your actual code an `Arg<N, V>` won't hold onto a value of type `V`, but it will presumably be doing *something* related to type `V`.  Maybe a method like `validate(candidate: V): boolean;` or something.  But for this example, I'm just giving it a property.

Anyway we can extend `Int` and `Bool` now:

```
class Int<N extends string> extends Arg<N, number> { }
class Bool<N extends string> extends Arg<N, boolean> { }
```

and the compiler will definitely understand that `Int<N>` represents a `number` property and `Bool<N>` represents a `boolean` property.  This understanding will be crucial in having the rest of the code below function properly.

This also means we need to do something to your `create` functions:

```
const createInt = <N extends string>(name: N) => new Int<N>(name, 0)
const createBool = <N extends string>(name: N) => new Bool<N>(name, false)
```

---

Now, the next problem is that there is no *specific* type in TypeScript that corresponds exactly to your `Options` type.  You can make something specific that accepts all valid values for `options`, but it will unfortunately accept invalid values also:

```
type TooWideOptions = {
  args: readonly Arg<string, any>[],
  execute: (args: never) => void
}
```

The problem is that for any given type of the `args` property, there is a particular associated object type for the callback parameter of the `execute` method, and `TooWideOptions` does not capture this constraint.  And it is currently impossible to capture this constraint in TypeScript without making `Options` generic:

```
type Options<A extends readonly Arg<any, any>[]> = {
  args: readonly [...A],
  execute: (args: ArgArrayToObject<A>) => void
}
```

Now we have `Options<A>`, where `A` represents the type of the `args` property (an array of `Arg` elements), and where the callback parameter of the `execute` method is of type `ArgArrayToObject<A>`, which we need to define.

---

How can we do that?  Here's a possible implementation:

```
type ArgArrayToObject<A extends readonly Arg<any, any>[]> = 
  { [T in A[number]
     as T extends Arg<infer N, any> ? N : never
  ]: T extends Arg<any, infer V> ? V : never } extends 
  infer O ? { [K in keyof O]: O[K] } : never;
```

This type iterates over all the elements of `A` and builds a [mapped type whose key names are remapped](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as).  Each element is of type `Arg<N, V>` for some `N` and `V`, and we make `N` the property key type and `V` the value type.  For example:

```
type Test = ArgArrayToObject<[
  Arg<"str", string>, 
  Arg<"num", number>, 
  Arg<"dat", Date>
]>;
/* type Test = {
    str: string;
    num: number;
    dat: Date;
} */
```

---

So now we have a generic `Options<A>`.  If you could somehow represent an infinite [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of all possible `A` types, then you could build the specific `Options` type you want.  But this requires what is known as *existentially quantified generics*, which TypeScript does not directly support (see [microsoft/TypeScript#14466](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14466) for a feature request).

Instead, we will have to make do with leaving `Options<A>` generic in the usual way, and so you'll have to pick a particular `A` for each value of type `Options<A>`.  You *could* force the developers to manually [annotate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables) the exact type, including a specific type for `A`, but it's tedious and redundant:

```
const explicitOptions: Options<[Int<"age">, Bool<"isStudent">]> = {
  args: [
    createInt('age'),
    createBool('isStudent')
  ],
  execute: args => {
    /* (parameter) args: { age: number;  isStudent: boolean;  } */
    args.age.length // error, no 'length' on number
    args.name // error, no 'name' on args
    args.isStudent // okay
  }
}
```

This works how you want, but it's not fun to write out both `Options<[Int<"age">, Bool<"isStudent">]` and `[createInt('age'), createBool('isStudent')]`.

---

The final way to deal with this is to introduce a generic helper function, to get the compiler to *infer* `A` for you:

```
const asOptions = <A extends readonly Arg<any, any>[]>(options: Options<A>) => options;
```

This function just returns its input, so it doesn't serve any purpose *at runime*.  But at compile time, it constrains `options` to be of type `Options<A>` for some `A` that the compiler infers:

```
const options = asOptions({
  args: [
    createInt('age'),
    createBool('isStudent')
  ],
  execute: args => {
    /* (parameter) args: { age: number;  isStudent: boolean;  } */
    args.age.length // error, no 'length' on number
    args.name // error, no 'name' on args
    args.isStudent // okay
  }
});
```

You can verify that `options` is still of the same type as the previously manually annotated version without forcing you to write it out:

```
// const options: Options<[Int<"age">, Bool<"isStudent">]>
```

---

So that's it.  Now we have working code that can represent and enforce the constraint between the `args` property and the `execute` method of a value of an `Options`-like type.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7#code/PTAEE0HsFdQOwKYICagC6VAuBjSyF0ALQtATwAdDIAzUANwEMAbaUoxtUAQQCcBzADwA5AHyheCCpIDO2NDIA0oGZgDuhRpNABbRgGsAlnH48BI5QDVRALgCwAKBzNGMmWaHCsADzTZk7jJovMb8VuIA3o6goBTQAEbMhjigeHBBvNA4GLwAFNKQftko8Iw6CDagwsoFRX6oTKwVoJYAlKARoAC+jj1OLm6gAJJwaCI+fnABKsGh4gi+-u58nspw0DrxCLyR3Y7Oru4AQpCQzOMLk9MZcxNLHhag8afMCIxwu337kOlcOJKcBAjLgAXlAF0WU0CsxMolycDKzWE7RB4kQamGoxEcIR5WUAAZWt9fqkAX4TmdQGCIVdoSFYfDEZVkVS0QgMRTzmJGXjQDQWHIiQ5HCBQPxDPRsKB3tLeLxGGR0JRqHQVu4EK9yqMlKA1BwuIZ3GgSKBIPEAFYIbJKqimujGzQCdw4FjMeKMHD6WJaRF+XgAfkc5FtKz48rIABVIAB5C1WsbcO5QiRvZA-ZiKlaCd5kZQ50QAbQAuuIQdEOqACxHQMYeAX1pttkXyzFXKBq5d7lnjDRtlU83AyOJ-VVQJVEJLeC3QEXKh3IdMsznlD2+9ZQCPLGP4AhJ90kwFy6veKBoxuKwWANI1uCgfQIMi0U+z09Xov78e77YAbkcIrAqjKDQkAngsZQUK8lRBsq7YIEEVIeGGCpRrGlrZIIBZZgARBkWHKDcsLKNhDZ4fAGxbDsRHmFhyCcKRAAigKiCWv4OMAABUNqEBGcGgh004ZJUBH8KxMQxA247kT+060WglSMX4rFdKA7HAH+bFgMIkBqMoDraIa8CYDIVA4IYNDJFxp4UGghg-O4erJEQuqGMwzCpHZwSMLWWj8O47yoAsVrQH4xCEGoCqgI+sDhaMrHBtxpwAOqGAQ0bWbZ6QIVEDitk6lQAmmcAZg8wkDkOxaKOWgU4MFzS5D5MifpOKLiPQkApb06misYQSppFMCpDKej3tKYrYNsFlpTZdmCNw4jxbqJDaImeBynBFA-NMGDSreWjhnaHiNdBtpTRlMizQe7gFemmbmMuO3lSWWXlg1+WpjdlYAHTfdwRaVTlPhBX4lT1XliFyshMZxuhc0tQw7XIJ1woabo7zQK6irGVaZlkKEPA1u4ZBZPoZDqWk8ELBBySGGgp12ZUdPpBhwKCFhjD8AgWGiMonKs4aADKaDQAQoxc09YLZblvmVAW07-G8fjArkADk7MIMrrT-WJpIKwgnIqwLQsi2gGvln9VXeEDzQNay-EAzEHGgPkPrlH67SvRWauSY2vDfjEhvC-IlTPGcbxwH7+6qdODWfWrn2vCYxqgKK2y8CBayYMrCf8MayumreDYUdHTqfbihAp3K6eGaAytl3nPyyr5xe+Z9AfG8nYCQPoCrln0XzI6K-moyNjCgCQzBUCeKXyDTio0NAuDTbe23HqFXH2E4HnSjIjPuNSiadsm11FbdQj3fmxZwpA6X01ZS-nbDtvX-frHEvBz9nQhri77kkuN41lY5ZkiBKMFWasNZazEvLQE+tlZt3kKbAG5sAbVVqpUG2qI7ba0ds7eUrttjuzBp0L2ZEfYR3gaMYOLww4R2UlHe2-9Y4c3jtgHOTkK5p14BnGu2dc751IUXBhMcy4dywJXLh1da6InrrtJ0zcZCtxkILQOoxRFdx7gDPurRX4o3JlwD+t9d7MyxGzDmXMeYvD5koo28gxaiHUkAA)

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you are looking for

```
class Arg<Name extends string> {

    name: Name

    public constructor(name: Name) {
        this.name = name
    }

}

class Int<Name extends string> extends Arg<Name> {}
class Bool<Name extends string> extends Arg<Name> {}

const createInt = <Name extends string>(name: Name) => new Int<Name>(name)
const createBool = <Name extends string>(name: Name) => new Bool<Name>(name)

type Unpacked<T> = T extends (infer U)[] ? U : T;

type Options <T extends (Int<string> | Bool<string>)[], V extends Unpacked<T> = Unpacked<T>>= {
    args: T,
    execute: (args: Record<V['name'], V>) => void
}

const args = [
        createInt('age'),
        createBool('isStudent')
    ]

const options: Options<typeof args> = {
    args,
    execute: args => {
        args.age
        args.age.length // Should be error, property 'length' does not exist on type 'number'.
        args.name // Should be error, property 'name' does not exist in 'args'.
        args.isStudent // Ok, boolean.
        
    }
}
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECCBOBzAPAOTAWwKbSwDwBcsA7AExggPgEtjEA%20aAbwCgXoPpjMsAuadNjadoABwCuAIxDVg0YAHtileOOAEF8ABTds-QVgCUzdiM4EAFtQgA6XTgC8XHqY4BfNh5ahIMAJLEBGg8uIQk5NAqtAyhRGQwCCgGjEwePlDQAEIKCiDB2LHhFFTRjPhxEYn5WCleisoE8vBYYEQBjU7VhfGRJXT0Ojz6PMYOjMRYAO7Q7dUD9obeSpRNLUTZudCdBt0RUf2DegIjW%20NTWTl5yYdGbAQAnqI4AKrEomDAANZYpMgAKownH9djAtLQAGZYeDQZ6GADaAF1oAB%20GHQfh-ADcd0eOAA8qICNRltB-iDoFpZvsYgAfC65ZDU%20jwhEAGmgADVya93l8fv9ATC3h9vr8AfQnKwRGAkBAMazXKEsMBxER%20FoZYg5dAAErKzS-DlwgDk9mNbM5zNO0AAbgpqKQWHVlo1NTAnHDFSJgM1Wlh2lpjWBEFhjYYFWZOD61lgNiBA9YAMoEcSkEgEMOKhFseorBSE4nKfgEonLZAPJ4KcHQN2CqWcN0Rzj4ZWqvg12XW%20uRt02YNYL0N2V9kM2EAkRCWaAAemn0ETFgU4hApGgkhwUPgmnZoi3T3gD2gxvHdEsxugpAUWBgxAUjXw1kaSmgFZwpvEGHX8GNNkHHF79gznOC5Liua4bvAW7wDue5Qoepo8Oel7Xlwd6hI%200C0Eebo-n%20HZajYSYpmmgRAdAeKfOykiXC0xC-pGHCKh4bhAA)