# typescript Can an array type be converted to an object?

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

**In the type, is it possible to convert the array type to the object type?**

[image]

```js
class Ad {
    constructor(name: string, age: number) {}
}
type Ac = ConstructorParameters<typeof Ad>
// Ac = [name: string, age: number]
```

i want this

```
type ?<T> = {...}
type Ac2 = ?<Ac>
// type Ac2 = {
//    name: string
//    age: number
//}
```

Comment: Your actually asking for named tuple to object conversion -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69687087/transform-named-tuple-to-object.