# In TypeScript, how can I statically extract the name of parameters?

Tags: typescript, type-level-computation

In TypeScript, there's the `Parameters<T>` helper type, which allows the extraction of a labelled tuple type representing the parameters that a function expects. For instance:

```
function func(a: number, b: string) {}

type Args = Parameters<typeof func> // [a: number, b: string]
```

Is there a way to convert from this type to an object type? I.e., obtain this:

```
type ArgsAsObject = ??? // should be { a: number, b: string }
```

Comment: This is not doable per se, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69687087/transform-named-tuple-to-object

Comment: That display is just a convenience, AFAIK it doesn't actually hold the keys a and b, at least not in any way available to you to create a mapped type.

Comment: @JaredSmith For sure, it doesn't hold the keys at runtime, but the tuple type at compile time sure carries the name of the tuple elements with it. Too bad we don't seem to be able to extract them.

Comment: @Jean-PhilippePellet I think the problem is the can of worms opened by equivalence: is tuple `[a: string]` assignable to `[b: string]`? I can totally understand why they just went with making the name in named tuples inaccessible, although it is unfortunate for this use case.